# IIS Manager can't configure .NET Compilation on .NET 4 Applications

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5

i tried to configure the .NET Compilation Settings in the IIS Manager but all i see is an Error Message that tells me that there is an unrecognized element in the `web.config` file in `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v.4.0.30319\config\`.

A little bit strange for me is, that i get this error message on my Windows 7 System and also on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

While googling around a little bit all i found is this blog entry http://olegtarasov.me/2010/09/nastrojka-iis-7-5-i-asp-net-4/.
I tried the `aspnet_regiis -i -enable` command but that was not the solution for me.

Comment: what is the unrecognized element?

Comment: the unrecognized element is "folderLevelBuildProviders"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ok, i've got it.

The Problem is, that my systems a 64 Bit systems and the `aspnet_regiis` i've called was the 32 Bit Version. After calling `aspnet_regiis` from the Framework64 Directory everything was fine.

Thanks to Scott Hanselman http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf.aspx

Comment: excellente... Thanks much.  It took my a while to figure out what to do.  But if you run into this problem.  Open up a cmd prompt, navigate to the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 directory in the prompt and then run the above command.  And viola, you can then access the .net compilation settings.

Comment: "If you install VS2010 and/or .NET 4 first, then later install IIS, you need make sure IIS is configured to know about ASP.NET 4 otherwise IIS will have no idea how to run ASP.NET 4 applications."

Yes! and this command solved the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it worked. To be precise executed:

aspnet_regiis -iru

As Scott says:

```
If you are already in this state, drop to the command line and navigate to the FX install directory.  Then run "aspnet_regiis –iru". 
    Note if you are on a 64-bit machine, run this command from the 64-bit FX install directory – not the 32-bit installation directory.
```

Answer (score 5):

For my x64 Win7 machine worked the following command:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>` 
**`aspnet_regiis -i -enable`**

Answer (score 0):

I have to used command below to get it working. For more detail see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015129

```
aspnet_regiis.exe /iru
```

When I used aspnet_regiis.exe -iru (with a hyphen instead of forward slash) it didn't do anything. See below.