# ASP: SSL integration

Tags: asp.net

[Tried this tip](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) and while running the web application it returns an error

> Cannot read configuration file due to
>   insufficient permissions

I have no background on how to integrate ssl in my web app. Do I need to add something in the web.config file or any other thing to do ?

regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not related to integrating SSL.

The application pool identity that is running the site doesn't have read permissions on the web config - you need to give it the right permissions.

Comment: How is what? You need to look at the application pool advanced settings to find out what user that is, then give it permissions to read the file.