# Redirect web.config IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis

I tried to make a redirect in web.config, but I get a 500 error. The version of IIS is 8.5, but before I was on version 6. What is wrong with this syntax ?

```
    <location path="Test/test.aspx">
<system.webServer>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain/Test/IT/test.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

---

I get an this error message : Internal error - 500. I deleted the lines in web.config and everything works again.

I tried URL Rewrite feature, but I get an error.

"Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"

I am trying to fix with these instructions below, but the system asked me for user/password. I am as administrator, but those credentials didn't work.

[Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

The HttpRedirectionModule is installed in the server. Also, RewriteModule

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the HttpRedirect module? It is optional under IIS7+.

If that isn't it would help if you could post the detailed error message you get from hitting this locally if you can -- that will help narrow down the cause.

Finally, you might want to look into URL rewriting here, it is a new feature for IIS7+ that can handle simple url redirects like the above and much more.