# cant get asp.net page to load on my local iis

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-6

Hi can you please help me. I am struggling to get my aspx page to load on my local pc iis6 , windows 8.

if I go to localhost then i see the default iis page view to proove that iis works.

I tried to set up a site called "test" that points to my web site folder and it will not . see images bellow. can you please help?

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\\WebSite1
```

[image: enter code here]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you cant accessIt by specifiying the url "test", this is basically outside of the machine by default, you can either rightClick on the application => edit bindings,then choose a port to bind, then 
type in the browser http://localhost:<thePortNumber>, Or add the application inside the "Default Web Site" and access it via typing in the browser http://localhost/test, however the last method means the applications root will be Default Web Site so you might get problems with loading resources unless dealt with at your code

Comment: cool thanks. now I get this error. HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error , 
Config Error
   Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions , I added the config to the question. 

Config File
   \\?\C:\Users\andrew\Documents\WebSite1\web.config , do you know? thanks again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions