# appcmd.exe Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, appcmd

I have followed the steps at [Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

I also tried to manually set the rights to related files, but that didn't work, especially on `appcmd.exe`.

I am trying to update `applicationHost.config` to set IIS reset time dynamically, when my website loads on IIS. For this I am trying to execute the following code in `global.asax` file of my project:

```
string WindowsDir = Server.MapPath("~/Startup");
string command = WindowsDir + @"\Startup.cmd";
string outputFilePath = WindowsDir + @"\log.txt";
string arguments = String.Format(
    "/c echo Startup task (Startup.cmd) executed at {0} >>\"{1}\"", 
    System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(),
    outputFilePath);
// System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(command, arguments);

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = command;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

This works perfectly when I run my website in Visual Studio, but when I deploy it on IIS, it produces the following errors:

> Prevent the IIS app pools from shutting down due to being idle:
>
> `appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00 /commit:apphost`
>
> ```
> ERROR ( message:Configuration error 
> Filename: redirection.config
> Line Number: 0
> Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions. )
> ```
>
> Schedule IIS app pool recycles for 8:00 AM UTC time (1:00 AM MST):
>
> `appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='08:00:00']" /commit:apphost`
>
> ```
> ERROR ( message:Configuration error Filename: redirection.config
> Line Number: 0
> Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions. )
> ```
>
> Prevent IIS app pool recycles from recycling on the default schedule of 1740 minutes (29 hours):
>
> `appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00 /commit:apphost`
>
> ```
> ERROR ( message:Configuration error 
> Filename: redirection.config
> Line Number: 0
> Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions. )
> ```

Then I tried to execute following code:

```
string WindowsDir = Server.MapPath("~/Startup");
string command = WindowsDir + @"\Startup.cmd";
string outputFilePath = WindowsDir + @"\log.txt";
string arguments = String.Format(
    "/c echo Startup task (Startup.cmd) executed at {0} >>\"{1}\"", 
    System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(),
    outputFilePath);
// System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(command, arguments);

var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = command;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

string name = "Administrator";
string pass = "password";

startInfo.Password = pass.Aggregate(new System.Security.SecureString(), (ss, c) => { ss.AppendChar(c); return ss; });
startInfo.UserName = name;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Then it didn't work even from Visual Studio. I then reverted back to code that was working in Visual Studio (as mentioned above). And added the following tags in `Web.config` (inside `<system.web>` tag):

```xml
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="Administrator" password="password"/>
```

But that didn't work when I ran the website on IIS (7.5). Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (I was using IIS 8, Windows 8, C#, VS 2013), by code sometimes you have'not permissions. I was executing:

```
string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");    
string comando = windir +"\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe set site /site.name:test /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:mitest']";

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + comando);
```

And I get the Error: **"Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"**

At the end use the **ServerManager** class, first I reference this dll in my project:

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll**

then I use the code to manipulate the AppPools, Sites or Bindings:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    if (serverManager.ApplicationPools == null)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < serverManager.Sites.Count; i++)
    {
        Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPoolCollection appPoolCollection = serverManager.ApplicationPools[i];
    }

    if (serverManager.Sites == null)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < serverManager.Sites.Count; i++)
    { 
       Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection bindingCollection = serverManager.Sites[i].Bindings;
    }
}
```