# IIS Deploy asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have hosted `asp.net` application on windows 7 64-bit operating system (IIS 6.0).

The problem is I am able to browse some pages of the application while other pages are not opening. Browser response is:

> This webpage is not available

These specific pages are using some `.pdf` files folder and a `*.txt` file to read and write which are in root directory of application.

Is there anybody that knows what is the thing that I have missed during deployment?

It is like when I hit one page

1) http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/page1.aspx (webpage working file).
This page reads some gmail inbox and displays result after some manipulation.

2) http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/page2.aspx (*webpage not available*). 
Second page in same directory does not working. This page is reading/writing some `*.pdf` files and `*.txt` files.

Timeout is not problem here.

Comment: Could you add some more details/code regarding your problem? Simply adding a basic description with a vague error message isn't enough info for us to help you.

Comment: @Sam if you can't understand problem or not able to answer than ask what specific thing you need to know to provide suitable solution. If I have slightest idea about problem then I wouldn't bother to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you mention transferring to a new host.

There are several possibilities depending on what you are actually doing.

1. Security.  Generally speaking, *writing* files to the root of your web app is a very bad security issue.  If the system is properly configured on the new host then that is likely killing your pages.  Actually, writing files *anywhere* is generally a bad idea unless you have taken the time to configure it and know what you are doing.
2. PDF/TXT file delivery.  The IIS server needs to have it's mime types properly configured in order to deliver those types of files to the browser.  If you are linking directly to a file with a .pdf or .txt extension and having a problem then the server might be misconfigured for those.

The best thing to do would be to change your web.config file so that it will give you the actual error message.  You can do this by changing the `customErrors` element to have `mode=Off`

Note that you might also have to configure your browser to turn off "friendly http errors" if using IE for browsing.

Comment: thanks buddy. It was security issue, I need to give full control to IIS_IUSER. This will help if anyone needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions

Answer (score 0):

use proper/correct activeX for displaying the PDF (Adobe comes with a free Active X dll (even for Reader) called AcroPDF.dll)

Comment: no issue with dlls. Code is working fine on localhost and on other hosting server. I am trying to transfer code from one host to other.