# Deploying a Web Site project did not work

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, visual-studio-2013, localhost

I was Working through Microsoft's example on [Deploying a Web Site Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx).  As the example suggested, I used the tool to place the compiled website in a local directory, and then creating a virtual directory in IIS and pointing it to that directory.  Then I converted the virtual directory to an application.  I tried browsing to the local website (http://localhost/TestSite03/SamplePage.aspx) but got an error that it could not access the config file due to permissions.  I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions) and decided that I should add IIS_IUSRS to the site.  I did this by right clicking on TestSite03 in IIS Manager and choosing "Edit Permissions".   After that it just stopped working.  The browser would spin when I went to the site, and eventually display a 'page not available' page.  Same thing when I go to http://localhost now also.  I tried removing the application, but localhost is still not working.  I did look at other values while I was trying to get the TestSite03 working, but I don't think I made any other changes.  Anyone know what I might have done wrong here?

Things I tried for localhost not working:

- Reordering the default page configuration.
- Restoring the default page order to inherited value.
- Adding a default.htm page.
- Making the directory browsable.
- Restarting the Default Web Site
- Rebooting the computer
- Checking permissions
  -

Possibly Relevant info:

- Windows 10,
- Visual Studio 2013
- .Net Framework 3.5 used for the test site
- Chrome and edge browsers.