# Porting over an apache2 website to IIS

Tags: .net, iis, apache2

I wrote a website using angularJS and host it on an apache2 server(uses angularJS for frontend). I'm wondering how I would port this over to a .NET framework so that I can host it on an IIS server.

Comment: That depends on your server-side code; the angular front-end is of no concern when switching from apache to IIS.

Comment: There is no backend for my website right now. It's all frontend at the moment. Is it as easy as drag and dropping it?

Comment: If you don't have any virtual directories (or whatever the correct apache equivalent to this IIS term is) it's really just drag-n-drop.

Comment: Hmm ok, but how would I get the iis to know what folder to look for the website? Sorry for stupid questions, I'm seriously that new to windows programming.

Comment: Works pretty much the same like apache: Either put your stuff into the default web root dir or create a new Website pointing to the desired folder.

Comment: I keep getting a "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions" error

I'm running windows as an unpriv user, but I ran iis as admin... I don't get how to get rid of this error...

Comment: [Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5615296/205233) should have answers for this problem. If nothing there solves it, you'll have to add some info about your specific scenario (folder, application pool user, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the link that fixed the error messages, but now I find that the webpage simply hangs...

Note, I am doing a direct port from apache2 on linux (if that matters) over to iis therefore I have no web.config file. I was under the assumption that it isn't needed... but with or without one the website simply hangs and never loads.