# Unable to load web site throwing error as: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

Web site is hosted on localhost on IIS 10.0 but throwing error while loading.

[image]

Comment: Which OS are you using? If it is 32bit, you need to enable 32bit application in application pool.

Comment: Can you read the error and do a web search for it?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I'm using window 10 64bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Try to solve it as per given link, please let me know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I have check security tab for web.config file but not found for IIS_IUSRS. As I found solution to allow read permission for IIS_IUSRS. How to add this for web.config?

Comment: @Kaishu for now try to add permission for everyone user and lets see if you can run application.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, In file explorer it is allowed to all user but I don't know what to do with IIS setting??

Comment: @Kaishu If you have given permission from explorer, it should work.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, It was working before but suddenly make some changes to IIS and from then it is not working. I don't understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you just check whether your IIS is working fine or not? Just write http://localhost/ and check what you get?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I'm getting the same error..!

Comment: @Kaishu So I thought that your IIS is corrupted. Please reinstall it and check again.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, but other web site hosted on IIS works fine, just problem with this one...

Comment: @Kaishu Ohh, you just told me before that when you browse localhost it gives you an error. So it should not  gives you an error. Please try again and make sure what you get when you try to browse, localhost.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, try to reset IIS still the same error!

Comment: Ohh... can you post your web.config here?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I have added web.config here please let me know is there any error. [web.confg](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=36291887131184516633)

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, but it was working before, so how error could be in web.config??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107809/discussion-between-kaishu-and-piyush-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which solved my problem:

1. Created `IIS_IUSRS` and allowed access to folder containing application.
2. Also created `IUSR` and allowed access to folder containing application.
3. Restart `IIS`.