# IIS new application site for SHARED network drive - Cannot read configuration file (web.config)

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I read this ([Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)) but it does not cover my case because this is SHARED network drive on the site in Windows Server 2012

1. I have network shared drive W:\Repository
2. I create new Application Site named Repository with physical path W:\Repository and application pool .NET v4.5 Classic (required by this application)
3. I set domain username with which I should connect to that drive
4. After that I try Explore for my new Site (Repository) and it opens correctly folder and its files
5. I must set Windows authentication for this site. I try to click on Authentication in IIS site but receiving an error: **Cannot read configuration file.**  for this file W:\Repository\web.config

I do not have this web.config file and I read on one site that it is not needed to have it, system is just checking if it exists.("Even if there is no config file at that location, the worker process identity (and/or the IIS_IUSRS group) needs at least Read access to the directory so that it can check for a web.config file in that directory")

What I am missing since I need to set authentication and I am alwyas getting this error?