# HTTP Error 500.19 - Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I'm new to this since I've registered for long time. 
I have query regarding the

> "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error", which says "Cannot read
>   configuration file due to insufficient permissions".

The solutions on relevant post didn't solve my issue yet. I have Administrator right only on my local machine. Still getting same error, after changing the permission for users (IUSR, IIS_IUSRS), I have reset the IIS and re-boot the machine too. Is there any further steps to follow?

I'm using IIS 8 and ASP.NET, Windows 7 - 64bit.

Appreciate your help.

[Answer followed and from the Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Is your code folder in a network path. Also try changing application pool identity to Local System as that's the highest privileged user and will rule out any permissions issue

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for the response. No,  the folder is in local machine. When I tried, the basic settings of the Authentication and test the settings in IIS, that is working fine and initially it was not Authenticated. Still I'm getting this error.

Comment: what authentication is enabled now and did you try changing application pool identity to Local System ?

Answer (score 0):

I was developing an ASP.net project in Visual Studio.

I pointed the IIS site path to the Visual Studio publish folder:

C:\Users\User\source\repos\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\Release\Publish

When I used IIS to open the project I got the same error.

I realized there is a permission with IIS accessing that folder.

To work around this, I moved that folder to the C drive:

C:\ProjectName\

I then edit the site Path in IIS to point it and it worked for me.