# Run ASP.NET project in IIS without "publishing"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

IIS 7.5 installed in windows features.

VS 2012 asp.net project.

There is a server with IIS and I need to upload asp.net application to it to make it available to local network. There is no VS installed in the server.

There is a developer PC with VS.

Is there a way to just upload updated .aspx and .cs files to IIS folder without publishing anything and so do updates to the local website? Publishing is not an option at all. And please don't say "but you still can publish it" or "why don't you want to publish".

My general task is to make the local website in IIS folder updateable by just uploading updated aspx files to the folder without freaking publishing anything. So I have this project folder on IIS server with all the aspx and cs files just like the original project and all I need is to throw updated files into it to update the app.

Project files are on the IIS server. So now I can see the content of the project folder in IIS manager.

Doesn't load any page, just loading and loading infinitely.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for the account running the application pool in IIS to access the files of the project? That would be my first guess.

Comment: Please have a look on link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Have you looked in the "Event Viewer" on the server to see if something is being logged for why isn't loading a first page? Could you consider trying a simpler application first to see that everything is there on the server to make this work?

Comment: If it is a website project, you should be able to push both aspx and cs files without issue. If it's a web application project, then you won't be able to change any `.cs` files without compiling the application, but even then you don't need to publish. you just need to push the bin folder.