# Why is my file supposedly unable to be read due to insufficient permissions (HTTP Error 500.19), when it has no restrictions on it?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, file-permissions, internal-server-error, configuration-files

I'm getting this error when I try to run a ASP.NET site (my first time trying to get it to run):

[image]

Yet looking at the file implicated (\C:\EnhancedSalesReporting\customerreportingnet\customerreportingnet\web.config), it doesn't seem to have any restrictions / insufficient permissons:

[image]

[image]

What is really the problem here, or what must I do to get beyond this frustrating block?

asp.net web.config 500.19 internalservererror configfile insufficientpermissions permissions

### UPDATE

When I approached it differently by creating a Virtual Directory in IIS, pointing it to the location of these files, and then in VS selecting File > Open Website..., I fared no better, really. The err pages are different, but I'm stuck either way. That roadblock is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496323/how-can-i-get-ie-to-recognize-my-default-page).

### UPDATE 2

When I attempt to follow the steps in the accepted answer in [the link provided in the comment by Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions), by trying to add "IIS_IUSRS" to Web.Config's Group or user names in the Security tab, I get "*Name Not Found - An object named "IIS_IUSRS" cannot be found...*"

[image]

Am I going about this the wrong way? I get the same results whether I try to edit Web.Config via Windows Explorer or from the Content View pane in IIS7.5 - is something else meant?

### UPDATE 3

Another hint from that post referenced above is, "*You should also check for the read-only attribute in the applicationhost.config file*"

That's worth a try, but which one? I have 9 applicationhost.config files on my hard drive, and four of them look like likely prospects, those in the following locations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express
C:\Program Files\IIS Express
C:\Users\cshannon\MyDocuments\IIS Express
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
```

Which, if any, of these, would it be advantageous to set readonly to false?

### UPDATE 4

This is in response to Michael Liu's answer:

Thanks, Michael;

I followed your steps, but still get the same err page. I had expected it to work, and so I was a little surprised (abashed, even) that I ended up with the same old err page.

BTW, I saw no "Details" tab in Task Manager, but there is a "Show processes from all users" in the "Processes" tab.

Maybe this is the problem - there are *three* w3wp.exe entries in Task Manager:

```
Image Name      User Name
----------      ---------
w3wp.exe *32    DefaultAppPool
w3wp.exe        classicEservice 
w3wp.exe        NETWORK SERVICE
```

Should there be only one?

### UPDATE 5

After restarting IIS7.5, I've got "just" two w3wp.exe entries in Task Manager:

```
w3wp.exe *32 (DefaultAppPool)
w3wp.exe (NETWORK SERVICE)
```

So is 2 one too many?

### UPATE 6

In answer to Michael's updated steps:

```
Application Pool == classicEservice
```

In "Application Pools" the vals for classicEservice are:

```
Status == Started
.NET Framework Version == v2.0
Managed Pipeline Mode == Classic
Identity == ApplicationPoolIdentity
Applications == 5
```

Following the steps again, but replacing "DefaultAppPool" with "classicEservice" definitely gets me on the righ track, for I no longer get the 500.19 err page. Now it is "hourglassing" on http://localhost/CustomerReportingNET/pages/custmaint_entry.aspx.

I think maybe the "/pages/custmaint_entry.aspx" should get stripped off of that; I'll see what I need to do to accomplish that...

### UPDATE 7

The first time it "hourglassed" until the cows came home, the second (and third) times it showed me this:

[image]

### UPDATE 8

I tried "Start without Debugging" and stripped off the back end of the URL so that it is just "http://localhost/CustomerReportingNET/" but it still hourglasses (or "blue spinning donuts" I guess) like a whirling dervish that has overdosed on energy drinks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Where are the "event logs" referenced at the bottom of the err page located?

Comment: When adding/editing user permissions, in the "From this location" section - Is `proactusa.local` your **Local Machine** (name) or some network  domain? You're only affecting your local machine so the source of users should be same (local users, not domain).

Comment: It is the extended form of the machine name.

Comment: It looks like the "insufficient permissions" issue has been resolved. The loading issue is likely a separate problem. To troubleshoot it, I would try running Process Monitor and looking at the file and registry activity when you browse to the site, to see where it might be getting stuck. For example, are .NET Framework DLLs being loaded? Is ASP.NET compiling your .aspx pages? Are DLLs being copied to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, and loaded from there?

Comment: Or perhaps it's a problem with the classicEservice application pool. If you create a separate virtual directory with just a "Hello World" .aspx page, and configure the virtual directory to use classicEservice, does the page load? If not, do other application pools work? Is ASP.NET working at all on this machine?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET works fine with new/modern code/sites. This is an old creaky legacy ("cave man days") bunch of code. IMO, we'd be better off leaving it alone and letting it die, but I'm not "the decider."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error “Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions” means that the IIS worker process w3wp.exe is running under an account that doesn’t have permission to access Web.config. Indeed, your screenshot of Web.config’s file permissions shows a very restrictive set of accounts.

First, determine which account w3wp.exe is running as:

1. In IIS Manager, find and select your virtual directory in the left tree.
2. In the **Actions** pane on the right, click **Basic Settings**.
3. Make a note of the configured **Application pool**, and then click **Cancel**.
4. Select **Application Pools** in the left tree (it should be near the top of the list).
5. In the list of application pools, find the one you noted in Step 3, and look at the value in the **Identity** column.

### IIS 7.5 and up (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2)

I’m going to assume that the configured application pool is DefaultAppPool and that its identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity, which means a [virtual account](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) is created by IIS for the application pool. (Let me know if they're something else.)

You need to allow this virtual account to access your application folder:

1. In Windows Explorer, open the Properties dialog box for the folder containing Web.config (C:\EnhancedSalesReporting\customerreportingnet\customerreportingnet).
2. On the **Security** tab, click the **Edit** button to open the **Permissions** dialog box, and then click **Add**.
3. In the **Select Users** dialog box, click the **Locations** button, select your computer (likely the first item in the list, and IBM-JBAKER from your screenshot), and then click **OK**.
4. In the **Enter the object names to select** text box,
   type **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool** (without any trailing spaces), and then click **OK**.

   - Alternatively, you can grant access to *all* IIS virtual accounts by typing **IIS_IUSRS** instead.
5. Back in the **Permissions** dialog box, the **Read & execute** and **Read** checkboxes in the **Allow** column should already be checked, so just click **OK**.

### IIS 6.0/7.0 (Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003/2008)

On these operating systems, w3wp.exe runs as a "real" account (such as NETWORK SERVICE) instead of a virtual account. Follow the steps in the previous section, but in step 4, substitute the actual account shown in Task Manager (or **IIS_WPG**) for **IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool** (or **IIS_IUSRS**).

Comment: Please see Update 4 - I have 3 of those processes running.

Comment: If you restart IIS, then immediately browse to just your Web site, do you still see more than one instance of w3wp.exe?

Comment: Via "Restart" or...?

Comment: You can run iisreset.exe as an administrator, or in IIS Manager, select the root node in the left tree and click the Restart link in the Actions pane on the right.

Comment: I hit "Restart" opened the site again, went to Task Manager > Processes, and now the only Image Names that start with "w" are wuaudt.exe, WINWORD.EE *32, and winlogon.exe ...?!?

Comment: Do you need to click *Show processes from all users* in Task Manager?

Comment: After restarting IIS7.5, I've got "just" two w3wp.exe entries in Task Manager:

w3wp.exe *32 (DefaultAppPool)
w3wp.exe (NETWORK SERVICE)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: I've revised my answer to find the correct account a different way. (I thought Task Manager would be fastest, but evidently not.) Please let me know which application pool and identity is configured for your virtual directory.