# How can I add the "Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider" Build Provider Extension to my website project?

Tags: reporting-services, build-process, rdlc, rdl, http-status-code-500

I am having no end of problems in getting a website to display (I was given a zip file of the files). Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450617/why-is-my-file-supposedly-unable-to-be-read-due-to-insufficient-permissions-htt), it is a problem with my Web.config file not being readable.

As it is right there in the project, I don't understand why VS is having a problem reading it. Perhaps it is something in the file's contents that is throwing a spanner or monkey wrench into the works?

The only thing there that really sticks out to me (I don't understand most of it) is this:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </buildProviders>
```

...and the reason why that stands out is because the "Reporting.RdlBuildProvider" part is displayed in red, as if it is unrecognized (nothing else in the files is thus flagged).

It is true that there is a relation to SSRS in this project, but I don't think a direct one, so I tried commenting out that part of Web.config, but it made no difference - I still get the "500.19" error when trying to run the site.

Nevertheless, I would like to get the red out, so how can I add the "Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider" Build Provider Extension to my website project?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </buildProviders>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```