# Start Stop IIS Application Pool

Tags: c#, iis, restart, recycle

I found this code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

...

void Recycle(string appPool)
{
    string appPoolPath = "IIS://servername/W3SVC/AppPools/" + appPool;

    using (DirectoryEntry appPoolEntry = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath))
    {
        appPoolEntry.Invoke("Recycle", null);
        appPoolEntry.Close();
    }
}
```

But when I try to use this code I have this error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation., StackTrace:    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)

What I'm doing wrong?
or how can get info about status of my application pool, and how can I start and stop my app pool without any special permissions?

I'am using built-in account: NetworkService

Comment: Please provide complete stacktrace.

Comment: This is all what I see in log :( I think it's because I don't have some specified permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager and Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool classes.

Example:

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
var appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.FirstOrDefault(ap => ap.Name.Equals("AppPoolName"));
appPool.Start();
```

Comment: I have "Insufficiend Permission", what permission i need? and how can I add it?

Comment: Message: Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

, StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)
   at [...]Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolCollectionCreator()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_ApplicationPools()

Comment: Please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615457/6137045) solution.

Comment: While suggesting MWA is the right way, you should also point out that such requires administrator permissions, and NetworkService is not qualified.