# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error when hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-express-10

I host my ASP.NET application on IIS Express 10.0 for remote access. It says :

> "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid." and "Cannot read
>   configuration file due to insufficient permissions."

I attached Screenshot below :

[image]

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for#14448906

Comment: Hi Najrul, welcome to StackOverflow! Try to give a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615457/9653205) to a previous question. It should work fine also in your case

Comment: Just change the directory (ie other than C: drive) will solve your issue

Comment: In my case, I pull changes from repository, and Visual Studio do not reloaded it properly, then I just restart VS - Error Code: 0x80070003

Answer (score 3):

Try to determine the identity of the worker process and grant read permission for the solution folder.