# When Publish sample project of .net core web app in IIS getting HTTP Error 500.19 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

[image]
Actually, there is no web.config file when run in local but after publish automatic create web.config file.

Comment: did you use .net 5 in your project ?

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615457/986259. This link will solve your issue.

Comment: @Jig12 there was already permission which you refer link but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to host asp.net core application on IIS, you should make sure you have installed the asp.net core host bundle.

I suggest you could try to download it from this [url](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and install it.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Notice:

If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after installing IIS.

Comment: i have not install asp.net core host bundle. but in same server framework application run without any error.

Comment: It's working after install host bundle thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was a permission issue in iis inetpub folder. Took the source files to a different location from inetpub and it worked