# Visual Studio - Cannot Read Configuration File

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to run IIS Express for any project on visual studio, sometimes the following error dialog appears:

> [Microsoft Visual Studio]
>
> The following error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express for project Accounts.web.Host. Filename: redirection.config
> Error: Cannot read configuration file

I have tried most common answers on
[Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions). Is there a standard approach to how I solve this issue?

Answer (score -2):

1. Right click on your project file
2. Edit the project file and remove the URL from IISUrl
3. Reload your project

Then it will work.