# Cannot read web.config file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis

I did the following steps:

1. Reinstall Windows server 2008 R2 SP1
2. Install iis
3. Install VS 2022 17.1.4 and created new ASP.Net core app (with standard template) and publish

   But when I tried to open the site I got an error

> 500 - internal server error.

When I tried to double click on the "Error pages .NET" icon in IIS manager, I got an  error on reading of

> File: ?\D:\monitor22\web.config

Access to the folder " ?\D:\monitor22" and pool credentials  is made from administrator. How I can solve the problem?

Comment: Windows 2008? Wow!

Comment: Everything worked for me on several 2008 servers and now this is a temporary forced solution

Comment: Tell us more about drive D. Mapped drive? Besides, since end of life Windows has unpatched vulnerabilities, expect that people here have no way to assist you much.

Comment: Is D:\monitor22 the folder where your application is published?

Comment: Yes, D:\monitor the folder where app is published

Comment: There 2 disks of 2 Tb i Raid 1+0 , divided into C: and D:

Comment: Full control - is temporary solution , just looking for what the problem is

Comment: How is your application pool identity set?

Comment: I create new pool , set name - monitor24, framework version - 4.0, Credential = administrator

Comment: If you set the application pool identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity, can you access it normally? For security reasons, it is not recommended to set the application pool identity to Administrator.

Comment: There is some kind of mystery here, so I decided to try to repeat the same on the Windows server 2012R2 SP1. I gave permissions only to find out what the problem was. From a security point of view - I installed the 2008 server twice and immediately checked, it was unlikely that some kind of vulnerability was triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255800/discussion-between---and-yurongdai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with web.config file. you just need to give permission to read of file to IIS Users

1. On the IIS, open Windows Explorer, and select the directory of the web application.
2. Right-click and select Properties.
3. Select the Security tab.
4. Select the IIS_IUSRS user and click Advanced.
5. Select Full control permission and click OK.

For reference check following link [Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

check it and if this not okay to solve your problem then there is may be change in application pool.
For that,

1. Open the IIS Manager.
2. In the left pane, right-click on the Application Pools folder then click Add Application Pool.
3. Now fill the name as your project name
4. In the left pane, expand the Application Pools.
5. Right-click Trend, then select Advanced Settings.
6. Scroll down to the Identity field and select Local System from the dropdown list.
7. For the Predefined option, select Local System from the dropdown list and click okay.
8. In the left pane, expand the Web Sites folder.
9. Right-click OfficeScan, then click Manage Website > Advanced Settings.
10. For Application pool, select Trend from the dropdown list. If you get an inheritance override, select all and click okay.
11. Restart the IIS Admin Service. Perform the steps below.

    - Windows + R
    - In the Open field, type "services.msc", and then click OK.
    - Look for and select IIS Admin Service, and click the Restart link, located in the left pane.

For Reference check the following link https://success.trendmicro.com/dcx/s/solution/1098768-cannot-read-configuration-file-appears-on-http-error-500-19-when-accessing-the-worry-free-busin?language=en_US

Hope this will help you. The first option was helped for me when I stuck in same issue.

Comment: "Full Control" is in general a bad option to suggest. And setting application pool identity to Local System is over killing.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that the ASP.NET Core application's application pool is configured to run under an account with sufficient permissions to access the application directory.

Open IIS Manager >> Select the application pool used by your site >>    Click "Advanced Settings" in the Actions pane on the right >> Check    "Identity" under the "Process Model" section. By default it is set to    "ApplicationPoolIdentity", which should be the recommended setting.

Then you need to grant Read permission to the IIS_IUSRS group for the Web.config file indicated in the error message. Even if there is no config file at that location, the IIS_IUSRS group needs at least Read access to the directory so that it can check for a web.config file in that directory. (ApplicationPoolIdentity is the member of the IIS_IUSRS user group, it does not refer to a user, but a collective name for all program pool default identification users.)

Right click on the "D:\monitor22" folder >> Select "Properties" >> Go    to the "Security" tab >> Click "Edit" to adjust the permissions >>    Add IIS_IUSRS with at least "Read" and "Execute" permissions.

If you have manually changed the application pool identity to a specific user account, make sure that account has read permissions to the directory where the web.config file is located.

Comment: IIS_IUSRS (and all other users) has all permissins on the "D:\monitor22" folder,