# ASP.NET MVC 3 Deployment 403 Error on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm deploying an MVC3 application to a new server. The application runs fine on the development server (Visual Studio) and also under IIS7 on my development machine, but on the server I get a 403 error:

[image]

I have completed the following steps, but am now out of ideas. Please help!

- Using the same xcopy deployment technique that I used on my development machine, I have deployed files to the to the server and added the following permissions to the folder:

IUSR - Read & execute, List folder contents, Read
IIS_IUSRS - Read & execute, List folder contents, Read

- I have also installed ASP.NET MVC3 on server so additional required .dlls are in GAC
- IIS is set up and I can access basic html files (such as test.html that I have dropped in at the site route).
- I have checked in Server Manager that all Role Services are installed
- Have attempted to bin deploy by copying files from MVC install location and putting in the bin directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies

Comment: Have you tried deploying a newly created application using the Visual Studio Wizard?

Comment: Visual studio is not installed on the server

Comment: I meant to create this project on your local development machine and then deploy it. What I am trying to understand is whether you have a problem configuring IIS or you have a problem with your application.

Comment: I have deployed seperatley under IIS rather than dev server on local machine. It works without issue. It is just on the server that it does not work.

Comment: Hmmm the "You dont have permission to view ..." made me think that you had that problem. Any way good luck with your project than.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. Here it is incase anyone else has the same issue:

The Server I'm using must have had .NET 4 installed before IIS. This meant that .NET 4 hadn't been registered with IIS.

I noticed the issue when checking IIS config. Clicking the .NET compilation icon for the website threw an exception, presumably because the application could not be compiled.

This led me to a stack overflow post that directed me to hanselman.com

In short, I had to install VS2010 on the server so I had the Visual Studio command prompt available, and then register .NET 4 with IIS on the command line.

[IIS Manager can't configure .NET Compilation on .NET 4 Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738559/iis-manager-cant-configure-net-compilation-on-net-4-applications)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET4BreakingChangesAndStuffToBeAwareOf.aspx

Key section:

"I installed ASP.NET 4 and then
installed IIS."

If you install VS2010 and/or .NET 4
first, then later install IIS, you
need make sure IIS is configured to
know about ASP.NET 4 otherwise IIS
will have no idea how to run ASP.NET 4
applications.

> There's a simple workaround
>
> If you are already in this state, drop
>   to the command line and navigate to
>   the FX install directory.  Then run
>   "aspnet_regiis –iru".
>
> Note if you are on a 64-bit machine,
>   run this command from the 64-bit FX
>   install directory – not the 32-bit
>   installation directory.
>
> or for future reference, try to enable
>   IIS and the ASP.NET extensibility
>   option *first* when your are building
>   machines or VMs.  That way when VS
>   2010 or .NET are subsequently
>   installed, the installation will
>   automatically detect the presence of
>   IIS and will auto-register with it.